# Attendance system with CMOS fingerprint sensor

Tags: .net, fingerprint

I want to create a light weight attendance system for my small business for around 10-20 employees. I am planning use .Net framework for this. What I am not able to decide is - which fingerprint sensor to buy. I am looking for capacitive sensors (as they are cheap), but I am not sure if they can be used in such scenario. Also, if somone can suggest a SDK to use along with the h/w it would be just great!

Thanks.